# EntityFramework: how to modify edmx to change format of entity names and properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, edmx, ef-database-first

I am using the Entity Framework to generate data access code from an old database.

The database table names and properties are all named in capitals with `_` to separate words ie. `CLIENT`, `CLIENT_NAME`, `D_CLIENT_ID` etc.

I have written a class to transform these into camel cased strings:

```
public static class Extensions{
    public static string FirstCharToUpper(this string input)
    {
        return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1).ToLower();
    }

public static string CamelCase(this string input)
    {
        return input.Split('_').Where(a=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).Select(a=>a.FirstCharToUpper()).Aggregate((a,b)=>a+b);
    }
}
```

I am invoking this from my tt files and I have got to the point where my data classes and DbContext naming is the way I want it.

However I now get an error when I try to create a controller: *'Unable to retrieve metadata for myNamespace.Client'. Could not find the CLR type for 'myModel.ENTITYNAME'. (in capital)*

To fix this, I made my Data.tt decorate my data classes with `[Table("ENTITYNAME")]` and my properties with `[Column("COLUMNNAME")]` - however this did not make any difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can edit the edmx file with notepad and update the CSDL, SSDL and MSL if the entities and fields are less in count.

Comment: That is not ideal... It is a large db. I want to change the tt templates... it should just work. i'm sure i'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating it the same way in all three (or two corresponding) layers: CSDL/MSL/SSDL? I would suspect there is a mismatch between two of the layers.

Possible useful in this case - here is a library I wrote for creating/updating/manipulating EDMX files a bunch of years ago: https://github.com/KristoferA/HuagatiEDMXTools/

If you use an older version of Visual Studio (2013 or older) then I also have a free VS addon/plugin that adds renaming and db<->model sync etc. You can download it from here:
https://huagati.com/edmxtools/

**Update:** based on the comments below, I think you are renaming classes and properties in the generated code without making the corresponding change in the CSDL.

Instead of changing the generated code / tt templates: change the names in the CSDL and the references to those CSDL objects in the MSL. Then the default templates will generate code with the class/property/etc names you want.

Comment: I have changed the *Data.tt file and the *.Context.tt file to use the CamelCase naming. I didn't change the EDMX file.

Comment: I'm using VS2015

Comment: Ok, so the names used in the generated code does not match the names in the CSDL? If so, that would be the problem...

Comment: Instead of changing the generated code / tt templates: change the names in the CSDL and the references to those CSDL objects in the MSL. Then the default templates will generate code with the class/property/etc names you want.

Comment: That is not what I want to do. It is a large db... There must be a way to do it by changing the TT templates...

Comment: Sorry, as far as I know, the CSDL needs to match the code. Likewise the SSDL needs to match the database. The MSL is the glue that explains to EF how the two relate to each other.

If there is any exception to that rule, then that is outside of my scope of knowledge about EF.

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for, but it is helpful so I will award the bounty to you.